# PHP / MySQL: Login form doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, login-script

I've got a login.php file which looks like this:

```
include "myfuncs.php";

$connect = dbConnection();

$username = $_POST["username"];
$passwort = md5($_POST["password"]);

$query = "SELECT username, password FROM user WHERE username LIKE '$username' LIMIT 1";
$ergebnis = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_object($result);

if($row->password == $passwort)
{
    echo "Hi $username";
    $_SESSION["username"] = $username;

    echo "Login successfully";
}
else
{
    echo "Login doesn't work";
}
```

and a myfuncs.php file which looks like this:

```
function dbConnection()
{
$servername = "...";
$username = "...";
$password = "...";
$dbname = "...";

$db_connect = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    if ($db_connect->connect_error) 
    {
        die("Connection failed: " . $db_connect->connect_error);
    }
    return $db_connect;
}
```

Unfortunately the login form doesn't work - it always gives the error "Login doesn't work" even when the username and password matches with the database entry.

Comment: Try to debug your code to find out what is wrong.

Comment: Are you sure password is stored in DB using md5 ?

Comment: You are mixing mysql_ and mysqli_ functions. You connect using mysqli, but then run checks using mysql_ functions, which does not know about your mysqli_ connection. Update everything to their mysqli counterparts.

Comment: @ThinkTank Yes I'm sure, checked it.

Comment: What are the results if you do a `var_dump($row->passwort)` and `var_dump($password)`.

Comment: @Oldskool This sounds logical, thanks. Should I connect with mysql and not with mysqli?

Comment: you have used LIKE for fetching username, Removed it once and then check it.Still it is giving you same result?

Comment: @coder No, the other way around. mysql_ functions have been deprecated for a few years now, you should really avoid them as they will be dropped with the upcoming PHP7 release later this year. So use mysqli_ functions for everything.

Comment: @ThinkTank The result for both commands is NULL

Comment: Where is $result defined?

Comment: Using `LIKE` for a login system is completely insecure, you want an exact match not a fuzzy match. Also `preapre` your queries to prevent `SQL` injection. Learn to use salt when hashing passwords to prevent attacks on your database, also you should change from `MD5` to `password_hash` and use `password_verify` to check to see if it is correct. Use `mysqli_error` to get error messages to help you debug the code.

Comment: dont use md5 to hash your passwords.  not secure. you also have spelled `$passwort` wrong in line 6. I would rewrite using mysqli and prepared statements utilising [crypt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) or something more secure.

Answer (score 1):

Arg, you are mixing a `mysqli` with class `mysql` functions. I dont think it works...

It works this way : [PHP MySQLI](http://php.net/manual/fr/class.mysqli.php)

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)

while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    (...)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you have error in your variable name in line #6.
try this:

```
$query = "SELECT username, password FROM user WHERE username LIKE '$username' LIMIT 1";
$result= mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_object($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your code. In myfuncs.php you use mysqli and after that, in your code you use mysql (without "i"). mysql (without "i") is deprecated, so you should use mysqli everywhere.

More than that, in your code you have:

```
$query = "SELECT username, password FROM user WHERE username LIKE '$username' LIMIT 1";
$ergebnis = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_object($result);
```

Please see the bold text from next two lines (it should be the same variable):

**$ergebnis** = mysql_query($query);

$row = mysql_fetch_object(**$result**);

You should have

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

if you will use mysql.